# Magic getter doesn't found a existent key in a private data array

Tags: php, oop, magic-methods

I have this class:

```
class activeUser {

    private $data = array();

    private $textStatus = array(
        "s" => "admin",
        "a" => "user",
        "p" => "notYetAccepted",
        "b" => "banned",
        "g" => "guest"
    );

    function __construct($id) {
        $data = db::singleton()->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id=$id")->fetch();
        var_dump($data);
        $this->data["status"] = $this->textStatus[$this->data["status"]];
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->data))
            return $this->data[$name];
        else
            return null;
    }    
}
```

And I call it here:

```
require "activeUser.php";
require "db.php";

$id = 4;
$data = db::singleton()->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id=$id")->fetch();

$exampleUser = new activeUser(4);
echo $exampleUser->nick;
```

The var_dump returns me the expected array with the indexes: "id, email, password, nick,
status, etc.". But just at the next line I got: "Notice: Undefined index: status".

Why? It's the first time I use php magic methods, but I don't found any sense at the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the local variable `$data` in the constructor, but referencing the member `$this->data` later. Pick one or the other. I assume you mean to set the member, notice line 2:

```
function __construct($id) {
    $this->data = db::singleton()->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id=$id")->fetch();
    var_dump($this->data);
    $this->data["status"] = $this->textStatus[$this->data["status"]];
}
```

---

It also looks like you are accessing `db` within the constructor, although this may not be in scope. Please elaborate on the contents of the `db.php` file to get an answer to this potential problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. Too much hours of code today. I update a previous version of this class (one without magic getters, but with regular ones) and I forgot to change this line.